# How to ensure that parallel queries to ext. system are executed only once and then cached

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, akka

**Server frameworks:** Scala, Play 2.2, ReactiveMongo, Heroku

I think I have quite interesting brain teaser for you:

In my trip-planning application I want to display weather forecast on a map(similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-weather)). I'm using a paid [REST service](https://developer.forecast.io/) to query weather data. To speed up user experience and reduce costs I plan to cache weather data for each location for one hour.

There are a few not-so obvious things to consider:

- It might require to **query up to 100 location** for weather to display one weather map

  - Weather must be **queried in parallel** because it would take too long to query it in serial fashion considering network latency
  - However **launching 100 threads** for each user request is **not an option** as well (imagine just 5 users looking at a map at one time)
  - The solution is to have let's say **50 workers** that query weather for user requests
- **Multiple users** might be viewing the **same portion of map**

  - There is a possible **racing condition** where one location is **queried multiple times**.
  - However it should be **queried only once and then cached.**
- The application is running in clustered environment meaning there will be **several play instances**.

Coming from a Java EE background I can come up with a pretty good solution using the Java EE stack.

However I wonder how to do this using something more natural to Scala/Play stack: Akka. There is an example (google "heroku scala akka") for similar problem but it doesn't solve one issue: Racing condition when multiple users query the same data at once.

How would you implement this?

**EDIT**: I have decided that the requirement to ensure that **weather data is updated only once is not necessary**. The situation would happen far too infrequently to be a real problem and **all proposed solutions would bring too much overhead and complexity to the system to be viable**.

Thanks everyone for your time and effort. I hope answers to this question will help someone in the future with similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

In Akka you can choose from multiple routing strategies. `ConsistentHashingRoutingLogic` could serve you well in this situation. Since actors are single-threaded you can easily maintain a cache in each actor. This routing logic will assure that two equal messages will always hit the same actor.

Each actor can work in the following way:

```
1. check local cache (for example apache commons LRUMap)
   - if found, return
2. check global cache (distributed memcache or any other key-value store)
   - if found, store the result in the local cache and return
3. query the REST service
4. store the result in the global and local caches
```

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334381/akka-framework-support-for-finding-duplicate-messages?rq=1) question, which I based my answer on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is an interesting approach and something completely different then what I would normally think about. I think actor side caching is actually not necessary: The weather update request for certain location would always be routed to the same actor and an actor can process only one message at a time. Therefore there can be no race condition where two actors are updating the same location.

Comment: @user822556 Some distributed cache solutions do not provide atomic write consistency, so it may be the case that just after caching the first occurrence, the cache will not return the cached value immediately for the second occurrence. This issue can be eliminated by the use of a local cache. A local cache also reduces the load on the global cache. If your cache solution supports atomic consistency, the local cache is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that I'll post my JMS solution as well.

Controller that processes the request for weather does following:

1. Query the DB for weather data. If there are NO locations with out-of-date data reply immediately. Otherwise continue:
2. Start listening on a topic (explained later).
3. For each location: Check whether the weather for the location isn't being updated.
4. If not send a weather update request message to queue.

   1. Certain amount of workers (50?) listen to that queue.
   2. Worker first marks the location weather as being updated
   3. Worker retrieves updated weather and updates the DB.
   4. Worker sends a message to a *topic* with weather data for that location.
5. When controller receives (via topic) weather updates for all out-of-date locations, combine it with up-to-date locations and reply.